# Is it possible to make git submodule update to autostash if there are uncommitted changes?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-stash

assuming that I have a git project that has been changed locally and remotely, so it is obsolete.

If I want to upgrade to the latest remote code without destroying my local work. Git can do it automatically using:

```
git pull --rebase --autostash
```

Unfortunately it only works for root module, for git submodule. I have tried the following options:

```sh
git submodule foreach git fetch
git submodule update --init --recursive
# git report error:
# Cannot rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
# Please commit or stash them

git submodule foreach git fetch
git submodule update --init --recursive --autostash
# git report syntax error

git submodule foreach git fetch
git submodule update --init --recursive --force
# git destroy local changes
```

What is the correct way to make submodule to behave similarly to root module?